# apply jQuery on specific resolution

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery for mobile Hamburger menu:

`jQuery( function($) { 'use strict;`

```
$( '<div id="header-mobile-menu">&#x2261; <div class="mH"></div></div>' ).insertBefore( 'nav.nav-header ul.genesis-nav-menu' );

$( 'nav.nav-header ul.genesis-nav-menu' ).addClass( 'hide' );

$('#header-mobile-menu').on( 'click', function() {
    $('nav.nav-header ul.genesis-nav-menu').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

});

The problem is that the menu doesn't close itself after been clicked. So I have added this:

```
    $('.menu-item').on( 'click', function() {
    $('nav.nav-header ul.genesis-nav-menu').slideToggle();
    $('#header-mobile-menu').toggleClass('hide');
```

But now its being aplied to all resolutions. And it is not good. So I tried to change it with this:

```
if($(window).width() < 992 ){}
```

And the final look would be:

`jQuery( function($) { 'use strict';`

```
// Insert mobile menu before the Genesis Header Right widget navigation menu
$( '<div id="header-mobile-menu">&#x2261; <div class="mH"></div></div>' ).insertBefore( 'nav.nav-header ul.genesis-nav-menu' );

// Add .hide class to .nav-header .genesis-nav-menu to hide it for small screen sizes
$( 'nav.nav-header ul.genesis-nav-menu' ).addClass( 'hide' );

// Toggle Header Right widget navigation menu for mobile menu
$('#header-mobile-menu').on( 'click', function() {
    $('nav.nav-header ul.genesis-nav-menu').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

    if($(window).width() < 992 ){
// Hide Header Right widget navigation menu for mobile menu if clicked
    $('.menu-item').on( 'click', function() {
    $('nav.nav-header ul.genesis-nav-menu').slideToggle();
    $('#header-mobile-menu').toggleClass('hide');
})};
```

});

And its not working... Please help who knows jQuery syntax.

Comment: Can you format your code, and white you're at it, make it a complete inline snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that click handler to only execute when the window's width is < 992, check *inside* the handler:

```
// Hide Header Right widget navigation menu for mobile menu if clicked
$('.menu-item').on( 'click', function() {
    if( $(window).width() < 992 ){
        $('nav.nav-header ul.genesis-nav-menu').slideToggle();
        $('#header-mobile-menu').toggleClass('hide');
    }
});
```